# How can my program return a none for values not available, e.g some movies don't have metascore

Tags: python, web-scraping

**Program suppose to return values for all 50 movies for its title, Metascore, genre, gross and if not available return aa none to ensure all elements in the respective list are 50 but currently give out 43 elements.**

```
url = requests.get(f'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&year=2017-01-01,2017-12-31&start=51&ref_=adv_nxt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
for t, m, g, r, c, i in zip(soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>h3.lister-item-header>a'),
                    soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>div.ratings-bar>div.ratings-metascore>span'),
                   soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>p.text-muted>.genre'),
                   soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>p.text-muted>.runtime'),
                   soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>p.text-muted>.certificate'),
                   soup.select('div.lister-list >div.lister-item>div.lister-item-content>div.ratings-bar>div>strong')):
    title.append(t.text)
    metascore.append(m.getText())
    genre.append(g.text.strip())
    run_time.append(r.text)
    m_certificate.append(c.text)
    imdb_rating.append(i.text)
```

**For loops return None value to values not present**

```
for v in soup.select('div.lister-item-content >p.sort-num_votes-visible'):
    votes.append(v.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'}).text)
    vote = v.find_all('span', attrs={'name': 'nv'})
    try:
        gross.append(vote[1].text)
    except IndexError:
        gross.append(None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some movies don't have `metascore` and some of them don't have `certificate` either. You either go for try-except blocks or conditional statements to get rid of that error. I used the latter within the following example. Give it a shot:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&year=2017-01-01,2017-12-31&start=51&ref_=adv_nxt'

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select(".lister-item"):
    name = item.select_one('h3.lister-item-header > a').get_text(strip=True)
    score = item.select_one('span.metascore').get_text(strip=True) if item.select_one('span.metascore') else None
    genre = item.select_one('span.genre').get_text(strip=True) if item.select_one('span.genre') else None
    runtime = item.select_one('span.runtime').get_text(strip=True) if item.select_one('span.runtime') else None
    certificate = item.select_one('span.certificate').get_text(strip=True) if item.select_one('span.certificate') else None
    rating = item.select_one('.rating-star + strong').get_text(strip=True) if item.select_one('.rating-star + strong') else None
    print(name,score,genre,runtime,certificate,rating)
```